# Google Play Billing Library

Tags: java, android

Na *library* Google Play Billing, alguém poderia me informar para que serve a parte `handlePurchase(purchase)`? O que ela faz exatamente?

```
@Override void onPurchasesUpdated(@BillingResponse int responseCode,
    List<Purchase> purchases) {
if (responseCode == BillingResponse.OK
        && purchases != null) {
    for (Purchase purchase : purchases) {
        handlePurchase(purchase);
    }
} else if (responseCode == BillingResponse.USER_CANCELED) {
    // Handle an error caused by a user canceling the purchase flow.
} else {
    // Handle any other error codes.
} }
```

É uma função obrigatória para o processo de compra ou, na verdade, a compra já ocorreu e eu poderia fazer qualquer coisa (notificar, abrir uma janela de aviso, consultar compra e etc.)?

O que significa essa parte?

Answer (score 0):

Uma vez que o método `onPurchasesUpdated` chegou na chamada do método `handlePurchase()` significa que a compra já foi efetuada e processada com sucesso na Play Store (daí o `responseCode == BillingResponse.OK && purchases != null`).

Sendo assim, como você mesmo imaginava, o método `handlePurchase()` é apenas um método para fazer pós processamento da compra, daí você pode exibir um alerta, salvar os dados num BD local, enviar os dados da compra pra um backend etc.